# Graphics trouble on Asus F55A-SX091D

Tags: graphics

I get system error reports all the time. It's got to do with XORG. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit with all updates.

```
arno@arno-X55A:~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0106] (rev 09)

arno@arno-X55A:~$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo
name of display: :0
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/arno/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/arno/.drirc: No such file or directory.
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, 
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 9.0.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_copy_texture, 
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_texture, 
    GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, GL_ARB_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_multitexture, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, 
    GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_MESA_window_pos, 
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_vertex_program, 
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, 
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_vertex_program1_1, 
    GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, 
    GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, 
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_OES_read_format, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_float, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, 
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_texture_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_timer_query, 
    GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_MESA_texture_array, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, 
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_debug_output, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, 
    GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_EXT_texture_snorm, GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_ARB_robustness, 
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_texture_storage, 
    GL_EXT_transform_feedback, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata

40 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x021 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x022 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09e 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a0 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a1 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a2 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a3 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a6 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a7 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a8 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0aa 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0ab 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ac 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ad 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ae 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0af 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b0 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b1 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b2 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b3 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b4 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b5 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b6 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b7 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b8 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b9 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ba 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bb 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0bc 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bd 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0be 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0bf 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0c0 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0c1 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x060 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None

60 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x061  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x062  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x063  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x064  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x065  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x066  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x067 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x068 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x069 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x070 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x071 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x072 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x073  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x074  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x075 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x076 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x077 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x078 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x079  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x07a  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x07b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x07c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x07d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x07e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x07f  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x080  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x081  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x082  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x083  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x084  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x085 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x086 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x087 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x088 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x089 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x090 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x091  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x092  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x093 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x094 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x095 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x096 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x097  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x098  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x099 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x09a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x09b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x09c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
```

X server log file: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/5612088/

Comment: Can you try quantal (12.10) or raring (13.04)? I am using a very similar notebook (A54C-NB91) I have used 12.10 and now using 13.04, both are very stable on it.

Comment: Have you tried the new kernel quantal as well as the graphics from the hardware enablement stack? - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do see a lot of EDID related stuff in the dmesg output, can you update your BIOS? [link](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&m=F55A) and after you update make sure secure boot is disabled, that thing is nothing but trouble, If you have issues using your backlight after the update run this command (if you are still using the 3.2 or 3.5 kernel this is not what you are looking for)

```
sudo sed -i "s/quiet splash/quiet splash acpi_osi=\'\!Windows 2012\'/" /etc/default/grub;sudo update-grub;echo 'Now you need to reboot'
```